# Coffer vs Chest vs Box vs Trunk

Tags: differences, word-usage, vocabulary

What is the difference between the words : **Coffer** , **Chest** , **Box** & **Trunk**

I had browsed many sites but could not get a crystal clear difference between them.

Moreover, when to use each one?

Comment: What definitions have you found from looking up the words in dictionaries?

Comment: @KillingTime I could get only 'pairwise' difference between the words but found it unclear to relate them all and distinguish each word with their meaning and usage sharply.

Comment: It's a big question: a tea chest, a treasure chest, a sea chest, a seaman's chest, a jewellery chest, a pharmacy chest, an architect's chest, a toy chest, a chest of drawers, not to mention a chest as part of someone's body, are all different things. And that's before I even start on all the different boxes.

Answer (score 1):

*Box* is an all-purpose word for a square/rectangular container of any size.

A *chest* is a large storage box with a lid hinged at one side - but a *chest of drawers* is upright, with drawers (!).

A *trunk* is a large item of luggage, too big to be carried by one person - often used for storage when the owner isn't travelling.

*Coffer* is an old term for a strong box for money or valuables. It can be used metaphorically now that most people with money use bank accounts.

Comment: A **trunk** and a **coffer** also has "a lid hinged at one side" . Do they have specific shapes and sizes and composition. Eg: lid can be flat or convex; composition is metallic or wooden. Can you add some clear pictures also, which would be helpful in understanding it better?

Comment: As I told you, a trunk is _luggage_, with locking clasps and a handle at each end. You can easily find pictures by googling _trunk luggage_. We don't use coffers nowadays, but they would be smaller (because the contents would be heavy).